# Gaussian mixture model sampling from specified cluster python

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, sampling, gmm

I have a piece of code given below that generates gaussian distribution and samples data from it:

```
input = pd.read_csv("..\\data\\input.txt", sep=",", header=None).values
gmm = GMM(n_components=5).fit(input)
sampled = gmm.sample(input.shape[0], random_state=42)
original_label = gmm.predict(input)
generated_label = gmm.predict(sampled)
return sampled
```

When I checked the original_label and generated_label, the number of samples in each cluster is different.

```
The number of elements in original_label: 
Cluster 1:0
Cluster 2:1761
Cluster 3:2024
Cluster 4:769
Cluster 5:0 

The number of elements in generated_label: 
Cluster 1:0
Cluster 2:1273
Cluster 3:739
Cluster 4:1140
Cluster 5:1402
```

I want to sample data from gmm with the same distribution of original input. Here, there is a big difference between the clusters of sampled and original data. Can you please help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Gaussian Mixture Models are a *soft* clustering approach. Every object belongs to every cluster, just to a varying degree.

If you would sum the soft cluster densities, they *should* match much  more closely. (I suggest you verify this. The huge difference in cluster 5 may indicate a problem in sklearn).

Generating a hard clustering that satisfies the GMM density model as well as the predicted hard label will usually be unsatisfiable because of cluster overlap. This demonstrates that the 'hard' labeling is not true to the underlying assumptions of GMM.